# How to create a text verification box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

I am trying to figure out how I can create a text verification box which is suppose to appear when a button is clicked and after the user must enter a certain value and if this value is correct the button should continue to do its normal functionality.

This is my code:

```
<div id="texto-cupon" class="panel-boton-canjear">
  <?php 
    if ($comprobarCanjear == 1 || $comprobarCanjear == 2 || $comprobarCanjear == 3) {
  ?>
  <input disabled=disabled id="canjear" class="btn" type="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CUPHONEO_BOTON_CANJEAR'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $valor->item_id; ?>" data-codigo="<?php echo $value->value; ?>" />
  <?php 
    } elseif($comprobarCanjear == 4) {
  ?>
  <input id="canjear" class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CUPHONEO_BOTON_CANJEAR'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $valor->item_id; ?>" data-codigo="<?php echo $value->value; ?>" />
  <?php 
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Inside the following `elseif($comprobarCanjear == 4)` is where the button appears and when this button is clicked on a text box should appear.

This button is calling an ajax code found below:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#canjear").click(function(e){
        if(this.tagName==="A"){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:jQuery(this).data("id"), codigo:jQuery(this).data("codigo")}
            success: window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, what is the issue you faced? Only thin I noticed is that ajax request may not work.

Comment: in your success function, open up a popup with an input field and validation function and then after validation proceed to window.location.href ...

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna ajax request works fine. I didnt notice anything, I just have no idea how to do what I need :(

Comment: @webkit could you give an example? Im not very good with jQuery atm

Comment: sure, I'll write you the jquery in an answer below.. you'll do the html/css.. also clarify for me what it is value the user is supposed to enter into the textfield?

Comment: @webkit the value is the `data-codigo` which is found in the button or the `codigo:jQuery(this).data("codigo")` found in the ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can just use browser inbuilt "promt()" function if you don't worry about the styling. Otherwise you can create your own window. First option is simple. Do something like below.

```
var input = prompt("Title");
if( input != null && input == "expectedValue")
{
    window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default"
}
else
{
    //invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but make sure to change some of the stuff to your own. Requires jQuery UI for dialog.

**Sample HTML**

```
<button id="canjear">Click me</button>
<div class="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" id="prompt" placeholder="Insert value hello" />
    <button id="test">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#canjear").click(function (e) {
        jQuery('.dialog').dialog({
            title: 'Prompt',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                jQuery('#test').click(function (evt) {
                    var theValue = jQuery('#prompt').val();
                    if (theValue == "hello") {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: jQuery(e.currentTarget).data("id"),
                                codigo: jQuery(e.currentTarget).data("codigo")
                            }
                            success: function (response) {
                                window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

EDIT: **input on page**

### HTML

```
?>
  <input type="text" id="txt" class="hidden">
  <input id="canjear" class="btn btn-info" type="button"...
```

### Jquery

```
$("#canjear").on('click', btnClick);

function btnClick() {
    $("#txt").show();
    $(this).off().on('click', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:jQuery(this).data("id"), codigo:jQuery(this).data("codigo")},
            success: function (data) {
                // check against codigo ** codigo is returned by the server right??
                if ($("#txt").val() != data.codigo) {
                    // invalid ** write code for invalid input.
                    alert("Please enter valid whatever into the field.");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // valid input
                    window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default";
                }
        });
    }
}
```

maybe this is closer to what you want..

Comment: Is there a way to have only the button I have to validate the field instead of a new button?

Comment: You want the same button you click, to open up a popup and then the same button to submit the form within the popup?

Comment: Do you really need a popup, or did you mean for this input field to appear above the original button?

Comment: The way I would "like" is that when the user clicks the button a text field should appear and once the user enters the correct value than it should just continue to run through the ajax I believe.